# Python: Search files in a given path but not the files in directories at given path

Tags: python

I have some code that needs to cycle through all the files at a given path. However I noticed some strange errors occurring and it turns out my code searches not only the files at the given path but all the files within folders which are located at the same path.

E.g `path = /home/Documents/place_to_check`

```
At path:
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    file3.txt
    folder_containing_other_files
```

I just want to cycle through the 3 files and ignore any files located within the folder `folder_containing_other_files`.

My code currently looks like:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            #Search for  file
            if file == "specific_file_I_want.json":
                print "FOUND FILE"
```

I'm tried to remove `dirs` from the first line but it throws the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** If using `os.listdir`:

```
import os
all_files = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, i))]

#Search for  file
if "specific_file_I_want.json" in all_files:
    print "FOUND FILE"
```

If using `os.walk`:

```
all_files = [ files for root, _, files in os.walk(path) if os.path.abspath(root) == os.path.abspath(path) ][0]
if "specific_file_I_want.json" in all_files:
    print "FOUND FILE"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to look into subdirectories, you can use

```
for item in os.listdir(path):
  if os.path.isfile(item):
    print item
```